# Will this Singleton Class Automatically Release Memory upon Destruction?

Tags: c++, memory-management, singleton, raii

I have created a Singleton class and I am wondering if my destructor functon will automatically release memory for the static variable named `instance`.

Will the following code automatically release memory?

```
class SingletonClass
{
    SingletonClass() 
    {

    }

    ~SingletonClass()
    {
       delete this; // or should I say... delete instance;
    }

    public:

    static SingletonClass* instance;

    SingletonClass* getInstance()
    {
       if (instance != NULL)
          return instance;

       instance = new SingletonClass();
       return instance;
    }
};
```

PS: Is it possible to just make `instance` a regular Singleton variable as opposed to a pointer? Would it be better code practice?

Comment: When exactly do you think this destructor will be called?

Comment: @us2012 I thought it got called when the variable falls out of scope &/or the application(.exe) ends.

Comment: @VaughnCato sorry thats a typo it should be a pointer

Comment: @VaughnCato yes sorry another typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This singleton class merrily injects **Undefined Behavior** in your program.

You have a `static` member variable which has automatic storage. As a global variable, it will get constructed before your `main()` routine is entered, and destructed after your `main()` routine exits.

Therefore, once your program terminates and exits the `main()` function, the destructor of your `SingletonClass` instance will be invoked, and it will try to `delete this`; however, the object was not allocated through a call to `new`, and calling `delete` for an object that was not allocated through `new` gives Undefined Behavior.

You can safely remove the `delete this` instruction: global objects are destroyed automatically when your program terminates.

**EDIT:**

After the edit to your question, what used to be a `static` variable of type `SingletonClass` became a `static` variable of type `SingletonClass*`. I suggest you changing it back:

```
static SingletonClass instance;

SingletonClass* getInstance()
{
    return &instance;
}
```

Actually, `instance` could (and probably *should*) even be a `static` local variable of function `getInstance()`:

```
SingletonClass* getInstance()
{
    static SingletonClass instance;
    return &instance;
}
```

This way you would not even have to provide a global *definition* for a `static` class member variable.

Alternatively, you can use smart pointers for taking care of the object's lifetime, but that's unnecessary here. Just declare the variable as a `static` local variable of `getInstance()`. In C++11, its initialization would be also guaranteed to be *thread-safe*.

Comment: if I remove `delete this;` from the function, wont I have memory I have requested and never given back?

Comment: @JakeM: No. That's only the case when you obtain memory through a call to `new`. Here you have a global variable which gets automatically destroyed when your program terminates. The short story is: you haven't allocated it through `new`, so you shouldn't deallocate it through `delete`.

Comment: @JakeM: Oh wait: the global variable is a pointer? Then I must edit my answer.

Comment: instance is of the type `static Singleton*` not `static Singleton`, that was a typo. So afaik its allocated by a call to new within the function `getInstance()`

Comment: @JakeM: OK, then in that case it should have been `delete`d, yes, but not inside the class's destructor (the destructor is called *after* `delete`), so someone must have called `delete` already if you are in the destructor. At that point, calling `delete this` would deallocated the object twice.

Comment: ok so the destructor doesn't automatically get called after main returns?

Comment: @JakeM: If you have a raw pointer, no. If you have a smart pointer or a `static` variable with automatic storage (so: `SingletonClass`, not `SingletonClass*`), then it will be called automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Use smart pointer like

```
 static std::unique_ptr<SingletonClass> instance;
```

It deletes the instance for you when program terminates. Avoid `delete this` in members of your code unless you really know what you are doing and what are consequences.